# How can I run webdriver-io outside of the test environment and still access the globals $ and $$?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

I am new to webdriver-io. I want to write a shell script that I can run utilizing webdriver-io. I have my code successfully working, but only in the test directory and only with webdriver-cli. How can I turn this code into a shell script and still get a successful response?

```
const assert = require('assert');

let linkedInUrls = []

const searchParamA = 'Daniel Dwyer'
const searchParamB = 'Madwire'
const searchParamC = 'Flux'

describe('google.com', () => {

    it('should have the right title', () => {
        browser.url('https://google.com');
    });

    it('populate search input', () => {
        const searchInput = $('.gLFyf');
        searchInput.addValue('site:linkedin.com/in '+searchParamA)
        const myButton = $('div.FPdoLc.VlcLAe center input');
        myButton.click()
    });

    it('check results', () => {
        const results = $$('.iUh30');

        for(let i = 0; i< results.length; i++){
          linkedInUrls.push(results[i].getText())
        }
        console.log('linkedInUrls:',linkedInUrls);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is in my shoes....
This is straight from: webdriver.io/docs/setuptypes.html

```
const { remote } = require('webdriverio');

(async () => {
    const browser = await remote({
        logLevel: 'trace',
        capabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
        }
    })

    await browser.url('https://duckduckgo.com/')

    const inputElem = await browser.$('#search_form_input_homepage')
    await inputElem.setValue('WebdriverIO')

    const submitBtn = await browser.$('#search_button_homepage')
    await submitBtn.click()

    console.log(await browser.getTitle()) // outputs: "Title is: WebdriverIO (Software) at DuckDuckGo"

    await browser.deleteSession()
})().catch((e) => console.error(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for just some simple script to be executed in the browser, probably WebdriverIO would be overhead. WebdriverIO great for tests and complex browser manipulations

Try https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: thx, I will check it out. I have a million potential use cases, so I am always looking for tech that works!